# python how to match text to other text?

Tags: python, list

What I mean is, for example this to be the final output:

```
example1 = text of example 1
example2 = text of example 2
example3 = text of example 3
```

```py
list1 = ['example1', 'example3',  'example2']
list2 = ['text of example 1', 'text of example 3', 'text of example 2']
for a in list1:
  if a in list2:
    print(a)
```

This is my first code, i can't make it work. Any help?

Comment: Shouldn't you be searching on `example 1`, with a space, rather than `example1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved the dictionary answer by Viliam Popovec because it had a problem. The dictionary values would then all be equal to "text of example 3"

I sorted both arrays and then simply matched the key with pairs using the same index.

```
list1 = ['example1', 'example3',  'example2']
list2 = ['text of example 1', 'text of example 3', 'text of example 2']

list1.sort()
list2.sort()

d = {}

for i in range(len(list1)):
        d[list1[i]] = list2[i]

print(d)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to store values. For example:

```
d = {}
for variable_name, value in zip(list1, list2):
    d[variable_name] = value
```

Then you can access the value under *example1* key like this: `print(d['example1'])`

P.S. `"example1" in "example 1"` will evaluate to `False`